# MYSQL - update each row from a table to set a column with other specific value on other table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i have 2 tables like this:

TABLE A
**CES | REG     | YEAR  | INC   | OUC**

---------------------------------------
C1   | USA   | 2015   | 0      | 0
C2   | UK      | 2014   | 0      | 0
C3   | BR      | 2015   | 0      | 0
C1   | RU      | 2016   | 0      | 0
C1   | USA   | 2016   | 0     | 0

TABLE B
**CES   | REG     | YEAR  | VAL   | DIS(%)**

-----------------------------------------
C1   | USA   | 2015  | 100    | 10
C1   | USA   | 2015  | 200    | 20
C1   | RU      | 2016  | 200    | 10
C1   | USA   | 2016  | 500    | 20
C2   | UK      | 2014  | 200    | 20
C2   | UK      | 2014  | 500    | 10
C3   | BR      | 2015  | 1000  | 30
C3   | BR      | 2015  | 500    | 10
C3   | BR      | 2015  | 200    | 20

i want to update TABLE A from TABLE B where year = 2015 like this :
**CES | REG     | YEAR  | INC  | OUC**

---------------------------------------
C1   | USA   | 2015   | 250    | 0
C2   | UK      | 2014   | 0       | 0
C3   | BR      | 2015   | 1310 | 0
C1   | RU      | 2016   | 0        | 0
C1   | USA   | 2016   | 0        | 0

*) Note :
TABLE_A.INC = SUM(TABLE_B.VAL * TABLE_B.DIS / 100)
TABLE A update from TABLE B where CES, REG and YEAR is same

for C1, USA, 2015 :
row 1 + row 2 TABLE B = (100*(100-10)/100) + (200*(100-20)/100)

for C3, BR, 2015 :
row 7 + row 8 + row 9 TABLE B = (1000*(100-30)/100) + (500*(100-10)/100) + (200*(100-20)/100)

could it be a single query?
thx

========================================================
oh well...
ive got the answer yesterday...

```
UPDATE a SET inc = (SELECT SUM(val*(100-dis)/100) FROM b WHERE a.ces=b.ces AND a.reg=b.reg AND a.year=b.year) WHERE a.year = '2015'
```

thx for the help :D

Comment: It isn't clear how you are obtaining the `INC` values which appear in `TABLE A` after the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A A, TABLE_B B
SET INC = (B.`VAL` * B.`DIS` / 100)
WHERE A.`CES` = B.`CES`
    AND A.`REG`  = B.`REG` 
    AND A.`YEAR` = B.`YEAR`
    ;
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55519